# Whenever I add a new fragment or new empty Java class it can not recognize its XML file and shows in red

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Whenever I am creating a new empty Java class or new fragment it is shows an error that it cannot recognize its XML file, even it is already there. It started happening after I update my Android Studio.

[image: See my code snippet]

What am I missing?

Comment: **`Clean`** and **`Re-Build`** your project or try to **`Invalidate Caches / Restart...`**

Comment: I tired clean and Rebuild but it didn't work,the app works just fine  it just shows the error which creates confusion when there is actually an error

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you didn't import "R" inside your class, if it so then you can import it like that:

```
import your_application_package_name.R;
```